# Accessing a data matrix using indices stored at another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

In matlab, I commonly have a data matrix of size NxMxLxK which I wish to index along specific dimension (e.g. the forth) using an indices matrix of size NxMxL with values 1..K (assume the are all in this range):

```
>>> size(Data)
ans =
     7    22    128    40
>>> size(Ind)
ans =
     7    22    128
```

I would like to have code without loops which achieve the following effect:

```
Result(i,j,k) = Data(i,j,k,Ind(i,j,k))
```

for all values of i,j,k in range.

Comment: You can be sure that values of Ind is between 1-40?

Comment: Yes, that's great! But what are you expecting from SO? Please elaborate your question according to the guidelines.

Comment: @Adiel: yes, I've added this assumption.

Comment: So see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vectorize your matrices and use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) :

```
% create indices that running on all of the options for the first three dimensions:
A = kron([1:7],ones(1,22*128));
B = repmat(kron([1:22],ones(1,128)),1,7);
C = repmat([1:128],1,7*22);

Result_vec = Data(sub2ind(size(Data),A,B,C,Ind(:)'));
Result = reshape(Result_vec,7,22,128);
```

Comment: This is specifically for 4-D matrix, am I correct that for a 3-D matrix the solution would have been even simpler, using [A,B]=meshgrid(...)?

Comment: Sounds like it is.

Comment: anyway, some vectors from the output matrices.